# Java: Using .split for Delimiters with Overloading (using charAt() and length() only)

Tags: java, string

So using charAt() and length() I am supposed to produce: (To add, I am not able to use arrays either)

```
string: one,two,three, delimiter: ’,’
one
two
three
string: one,two,three, delimiter: ’o’
ne,tw
,three
string: four,,five,,six, delimiter: ’,’
four
five
six
string: four,,five,,six, delimiter: ’o’
f
ur,,five,,six
```

I am not sure where to start with this one as almost everything I have found uses different methods than the ones I am allowed to use. I am not sure I am even allowed to use `.split` but I see no other way than using this. Here is as far as I have gotten on my own:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

        String a = "one,two,three";
        String b = "four,,five,,six";


}

public static void stringSplit(String a, String b, char del)

{
        String[] deli = a.split(",");
        String[] delim = b.split("o");

        System.out.println("%s" + deli);
        System.out.println("%s" + delim);
}`
```

What steps could I take in order to solve this issue while still sticking to the presets? I cannot seem to find anything that aids me in this process without using something different than what is allowed. Help not answers would be preferable if able. Will never learn if all I do is copy paste. It must call from a method and the function cannot return anything. The method must have the header of `public static void stringSplit(String s, char del)`

Comment: Well, I would change your method to take two parameters, not three: the string to split, and what to split it on. Then call your method twice. It will be simpler if you make the "what to split it on" parameter a string rather than a char, as then you can just call String.split directly.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet Thanks for your answer! But how exactly would I go about that process? I am unsure of how to call multiple times on one method.

Comment: From `main`, you'd call `stringSplit("one,two,three", ",");` and then `stringSplit("one,two,three", "o")` for example.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet, I see what you mean now. I am getting an error for  "string cannot be converted to a char" so I will move it around a bit to see what functions best while playing with the second function. Unfortunately, he specified it must have the header of `public static void stringSplit(String s, char del)` which is why I am struggling with this. So many easier ways to do this, but the point is to learn to call from another function. But I can only find ways to use arrays and other methods which is not helpful to me. (yet)

Comment: Ah, you hadn't stated that as a requirement before. String.valueOf (char) will help you in the method then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are after exactly, but if you cannot use the `split` method, you can simply have a method which takes 2 arguments, the string to be split and the character which will act as a seperator. Once that you will have that, you can iterate over the string and check the if the character you have is the delimeter. If it is, you then split and move to the next:

```
public List<String> split(String source, char delimeter)
{
     List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
     {
          if(source.charAt(i) == delimeter) 
          {
              result.add(sb.toString());
              sb.Clear();
          }
          else
          {
              sb.append(source.charAt(i));
          }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: @ npinti Your route is very useful! However, is there a way to get around using the array's? Those are not to be used. I never though to do the `if` statement the way you put it which is certainly helping move forward.

Comment: @NaughtyBear: You will need to use a dynamic data structure so that it grows as you add elements to it. Lists provide a `toArray` method to get you back an array. If you want to eliminate lists completely, you would need to go through the string first and count the delimeters and then create an array which is of size one more than the delimeter count.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] deli = a.split(",");
    String[] delim = b.split("o");

    System.out.println("%s" + deli);
    System.out.println("%s" + delim);
```

The `deli` and `delim` are `String array`. You can not print the content of an array directly. You need to iterate using `for-loop` (or while) over them and print each element individually.

```
for (String value : deli) {
    System.out.println(value);
}

for (String value : delim) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

---

```
System.out.println("%s" + deli);
```

Also you are using `println` method, which will print the content exactly. If you want to use format method then it will be like this:

```
System.out.format("%s", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> mySplittedList = stringSplit("one,two,three", 'o');
        for (String s : mySplittedList)
            System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static List<String> stringSplit(String input, char del) {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        List<String> mySplittedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == del) {
                if (temp.length() > 1) {
                    mySplittedList.add(temp.toString());
                }
                temp = new StringBuilder();
            } else {
                temp.append(c);
            }

            i++;
            if (i == input.toCharArray().length) {
                mySplittedList.add(temp.toString());
            }
        }
        return mySplittedList;
    }
```

**output**

```
ne,tw
,three
```